# Qt force QCheckBox to emit signal on setChecked

Tags: qt, qt4

If I called `QCheckBox::setChecked( x )` the `toggled` signal is only emitted if `x` is not the same as the current checkbox state. I understand the logic behind this, to avoid signaling if nothing has changed. However, in some situations where I have a more complicated widgets setup, I need the signal to always be emitted. This ensures anybody who has connected to the checkbox will receive the first state.

Is there a way to have `QCheckBox::setChecked(bool)` emit a signal regardless of whether the state has changed?

---

*My simple workaround now is to just force the checkbox into multiple states by doing `setChecked(!x)` and `setChecked(x)`. I was hoping for a more correct way of doing this.*

Answer (score 6):

Looking into the `QAbstractButton` implementation, I found the following lines of code:

```
if (!d->checkable || d->checked == checked) {
    if (!d->blockRefresh)
        checkStateSet();
    return;
}
```

where `checkStateSet` is a virtual function. QCheckBox overrides this and emits a `stateChanged()` signal only if the state changed.
I haven't tested this, but I think `d->blockRefresh` is set to `false` if you call `QCheckBox::setChecked( ... )` directly.

If this is the case, it means you could subclass `QCheckBox` and override the `checkStateSet()` method to something like this:

```
void MyCheckBox::checkStateSet()
{
    QCheckBox::checkStateSet();
    if( m_oldState == checkState() )
    {
        // emit the signal here, as QCheckBox::checkStateSet() didn't do it.
        emit stateChanged( m_oldState );
    }
    else
    {
        // don't emit the signal as it has been emitted already,
        // but save the old state
        m_oldState = checkState();
    }
}
```

where the header file contains

```
private:
    Qt::CheckState m_oldState;
```

which must be initialised to `Qt::Unchecked` in the constructor.

Comment: This might work, but having to subclass for this reason is a bit problematic: you have to remember in designer to promote, and all programmers must remember to use this class instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution which may or may not be possible for your case:

If you can be 100% sure that your signals and slots are connected before the checkbox has a chance to change its state, every connected class can initialize itself safely assuming the checkbox is not checked. This is because checkboxes are always unchecked upon construction.
This way you might not have to call `setChecked()` after connecting the signals.

However, This approach does not work if there is a chance a signal gets connected after the checkbox has already changed. I'm not 100% fond of this approach myself but it might be an option for you nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to subclass QCheckBox and implement the emitting of signals in that where you need it, for example :

```
class MyCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyCheckBox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QCheckBox(parent) {};

   virtual void setChecked(bool checked) {
            QCheckBox::setChecked(checked); emit checkWasSet(checked);
            };
signals:
   void checkWasSet(bool value);

};
```

Now use this class instead of the regular QCheckBox class, and you can connect to the checkWasSet() signal for whenever the check state is set.

Comment: `setChecked` is not virtual in `QAbstractButton` (according to docs).  Plus I want the mechanism to be generic, for any manner in which the state is set.  I also have to repeat the pattern for several other classes (QCheckBox was just my example here).

Answer (score 0):

You could emit the signal with the current state yourself:

```
checkbox.stateChanged.emit(checkbox.checkState())
```